# Radiobutton list throws null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to get the selected value from radiobutton list and post it to my database using linq to sql. My stepping though the code clearly shows there is some value in the variable which i get it from the selected value of the radio button list, but when i assign it to the column of my database table, it throws null reference.

Here is the picture of my code...[image]

Do you know where i am going wrong ?

Comment: I assume that you have forgotten to apply the [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) to the `RadioButtonList`. Therefore the (Selected)Value is the same as the text. Hence `notes` contains the text which is not the required `formid` that was entered into the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stat is actually the null value, not notes. So you're trying to access a null object's property, hence the NullReferenceException

look at your Auto's below.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, i am trying to store null value in my Status table, once i instantiate that to Status stat = new Status(), i am getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

your printscreen shows that your "stat" variable is null... hence the error